# Testing a bot using Direct Line

Tags: botframework, functional-testing

I have developed a bot that I want to  test. 
Due to few discussions ([Conversations.SendToConversationAsync crashes on Unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264251/conversations-sendtoconversationasync-crashes-on-unit-testing/43265239#43265239)) it seems that an approach is to make use of Direct Line. The bot must be hosted locally, so that the sent messages can be captured and evaluated on the bot. On this point, I am not sure about two aspects.

1. Isn’t there any alternative way to do functional test?
2. I was planning to do the functional test on the localhost using Emualtor and Visual Studio. Checking this github page (https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureBot/tree/master/AzureBot.Tests) I understand that a test case can be converted into a code in an easy way writing down an action and its expected reply.
   However I don’t understand the requirement and benefits of using Direct Line for the functional test?

Comment: What do you mean by `functional test`: based on your sentence about using emulator, it seems that you what to validate things manually?

Comment: I send a message to the bot. It understands it and returns a response that I expect according to the requirements. Using a coded script on node.js or C# I can automate my test. However, in the linked thread/question there a functional test using Direct Line was recommended. I don’t understand that….

Comment: With Direct Line you will be able to talk with a hosted bot

Comment: @EzequielJadib Exactly. What is the added value testing a self hosted bot compared to hosting it on azure for example? Functoinal tests can be done in both scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to test your bot:

- you want to automate your tests, and this is possible with Direct Line as you can write your own test client and define your own test logic. This is what https://botmonkey.io is doing, they can connect to your bot via Direct Line and run tests.
- I don't think you can write automated tests via Skype channel or via other channels other than Direct Line.
- Off topic but with Direct Line you can develop your own bot client using your own web stack or mobile stack. You can also send custom payloads and render your own cards with your own data and not be limited with bot framework's hero cards which accept only limited number of properties: (title, subtitle, text, image)